# Removal of Natgateway and add internet gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat

I want to remove nat gateway and make all instances that were in private subnet to get access through internet gateway .Please suggest me the procedure.

When I have added internet gateway and removed Natgateway then started getting API timeout,please suggest me the possible reason for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the NAT, and change the route table in the subnets to point to the IGW. You will also need to add public IPs to the EC2 instances if they don't already have them.

Comment: I have changed the route table in the subnet to point to the igw but not added any elastic ip because I don't need to connect to internet for now ,m.not getting why API's getting timed out.